# Mysql LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE - Chinese characters issue

Tags: bash, character-encoding, mysql

I'm trying to load an UTF8 CSV file with Chinese characters on it, only to discover that in my table the correct encoding is lost. My table has UTF8 as configured charset.

I'm using a bash script on RHEL 5 with MySQL command line client and my statement is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file' INTO TABLE 'table'
CHARACTER SET "UTF8"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Is there something I can do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I managed to do this. 
I loaded a text file which has lots of Chinese characters into my MySQL:

1. My text file is encoded with utf8,
2. my table is encoded with utf8
3. and I used your statement.

It worked.

I think you should try to convert you file into utf8 first and make sure your table is encoded with utf8.

BTW, adding **charset=utf8**, like `CREATE TABLE test (column_a varchar(100)) charset=utf8`, will make the table encoded with utf8.